# Equivalent of Array() in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

In VB6 you can do this:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Can you do a similar thing in VB.NET with specific types, like so?:

```
Dim a() As Integer
a = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Dim a() As Integer = New Integer() {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to .NET you will want to learn about the List collection and the flexibility it will give you in [respect to sorting, filtering, and iteration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41107z8a(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I normally use them, but I'm converting a VB6 app and taking the easy route for the moment.