# pass array of strings into COM object

Tags: arrays, vb.net, com, bstr

I gave in with finding data type that would fit following method:

1. I have COM object method which requires "vector of BSTR strings" (as COM documentation says).

It works perfectly from:
a) python (everything works from python BTW)

```
Visum.Net.Zones.GetmultipleAttributes(["No","Name","XCoord","YCoord","Name","SHAREPRTORIG","SHAREPRTDEST"])
```

b) VBS:

```
Visum.Net.Zones.GetmultipleAttributes(Array("No","Name","XCoord","YCoord","Name","SHAREPRTORIG","SHAREPRTDEST"))
```

c) but nothing can go with VB ('CComBaseContainer::GetMultipleAttributes failed' error is raised)

it tried such method `Out=Visum.Net.Zones.GetmultipleAttributes(In)` with following data types, everytime the same error:

```
Dim Out As Object
Dim In As New List(Of String)
Dim In(2) As String
In.toArray()
```

How can I satisfy this method?

PS. Quote from documentation:

> GetMultipleAttributes ( [in] VARIANT AttrIDs, [out, retval] VARIANT
>   *value)
>   Returns the values of several attributes for all net objects of the container. The attribute ID  have to be specified as a vector
>   of BSTR strings. The return value contains a matrix of  VARIANT values
>   consisting of the values of all objects and specified attributes. The
>   rows of  the matrix correspond to the net objects in standard order
>   (ordered by their keys). The  columns correspond to the attributes in
>   the order as specified.  Parameters [in] VARIANT AttrIDs  Vectorof
>   attribute IDs as in ATTRIBUTE.XLS.  [out, retval] VARIANT *value
>   Matrix of values of these attributes for all net objects  in the
>   container

Thanks in advance
i2

Comment: I'm in VB.NET, I cannot start indexing from 1 (can I?) `Error Array lower bounds can be only '0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following finally worked, but don't ask me why:

```
    Dim In() As Object = {"No","Name","XCoord","YCoord","Name","SHAREPRTORIG","SHAREPRTDEST"}
    Dim VisumOut(,) As Object
    VisumOut = Visum.Net.Zones.GetMultipleAttributes(In)
```

After million of tries it finally went fine. If you know why is that, please give us proper answer.

Powodzenia, Rafał!

Answer (score 0):

If this works in VBS:

```
Visum.Net.Zones.GetmultipleAttributes(Array("No","Name","XCoord","YCoord","Name","SHAREPRTORIG","SHAREPRTDEST"))
```

The this should work in VB.NET:

```
Dim a() As String= New String() {"No", "Name", "XCoord","YCoord","Name","SHAREPRTORIG","SHAREPRTDEST"}

Visum.Net.Zones.GetmultipleAttributes(a) 'you might need a() instead
```

Have a look at this question for clarification: [Equivalent of Array() in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241758/equivalent-of-array-in-vb-net)

Comment: however the structure which woredk is very similar (slight changes)